# Can I apply for a graduate degree in Cambridge (MPhil/PhD) after I have earned a Bachelor's from Oxford, or vice versa?

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate

I know that we can't apply to both simultaneously for undergraduate admissions. What about to each the other once we have completed our first degree in one? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Graduate studies are completely separate from undergraduate studies, so there is no constraint or conflict here.

Comment: Yes absolutely. I also think you can even apply for both universities simultaneously for graduate school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions on doing as you suggest, and indeed, I know a number of people who have applied for (and completed) graduate courses at the University of Cambridge after an undergraduate course at the University of Oxford.

Comment: yes, most grads do so, or the reverse, the Oxbridge combo degrees is a potent one